# Consultation about the best design for MVVM

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvvm

little question. I'm progrraming in MVVM design pattern (C#).
the View is an Excel add-in, and I want to run from the View_Model a method that found in the View. I thought about 2 ways:

1. Hold in the View Model a pointer to the View (the pointer type is an interface that the View and the View_Model inherit from, otherwise I would get a circular independence because the View hold the View_Model and the View_Model hold the View), and then run the method directly from him.
2. Create an event in the View_Model and sign the method in the View to that event in the View_Model pointer which I already have in the View, and raise the event when I want to run this method.

Somehow, way number 2 feel little like screaming in the street to only one man instead off go straight and talk to him normally. On the other hand, the advantage in way number 2, is that in the future if I would have other method that relate  to this operation I could just sign them to that event and not call them specially.

what would you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1 breaks the MVVM principle since the view model should not know about the view. Your approach is a bit like the MVP design pattern.

I would say method 2 is the better approach, it's perfectly fine for the view to know about the view model. It also gives you the flexibility to do whatever you want when that event is raised, say for example, if you wanted to use a different view and call a different method.

Also, this kind of thing can be done using a good messaging framework. The view model publishes a message, the view subscribes to it. The mvvmlight frame work has a good implementation of this, but I am sure there are others too.

Answer (score 0):

take an Interface, implement the view from it. And instantiate the viewmodel by passing this view.

lets say -

Interface

```
public interface IFooView
{
   ...
}
```

View

```
public Class FooView : IFooView
{
   private FooViewModel _viewModel; 
   public FooView()
   {
      _viewModel = new FooViewModel(this);
   }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class FooViewModel
{
   private FooView _view;
   public FooViewModel(IFooView view)
   {
      _view = view;
   }
}
```

Now, you can call the ViewModel from View, also View from ViewModel.